# Angular service ($sce) type side effects

Tags: angularjs

I have a string variable with html text to which was applied `$sce.trustAsHtml()` function. My problem is that the function changes type from string to json object. But I need to apply `trim()` function to variable and `trim()` can be applied to strings only. How to overcome this issue?

```
var myVar = $sce.trustAsHtml("some html text");
var strVar = "some another text";
myVar.trim() === strVar.trim(); <---- error here
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `strVar.trim() === myVar.trim();`, also you could try this

// still not sure why would you call trim on `myVar` but anyways you could do something along the lines of:

`$sce.getTrustedHtml(myVar).trim() ===  strVal.trim();`